# Anyway to invoke inapp browser in android via javascript?

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to control link clicking behavior inside an android app via javascript? What I'm asking is this.

Suppose there's an app with inbuilt browser, android webview. A new content with some text and links appears on the app, and when we click the link, it asks to 'complete function using' and third party browsers appear. But can we force the app to open those links in its own webview via javascript? If possible, can we handle different links with different behavior? For example, link 1 opens the link in third party browser and link 2 opens the link with inapp browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
      @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              // check url and depending on clicked url, 
              //open different views as you want.
          }
  });
```

Comment: I asked for javascript  method prashant, not via app's code

Comment: If I am not wrong,
you want to display two links in webview, when user clicks on them those two links should behave differently,
One will open in same or another webview and second link will open in exteral browser,

is my understanding correct ?